# Change Uni-Code (Emoji) size in console, using Python

Tags: python, resize, size, emoji

Want to change the size of an emoji(unicode) in console using Python language.
Rather changing the font size of terminal.
Currently using **VSCode** for python.

`print("\U0001F609")`

The above line will print the  this emoji in a specific size or pre-defined console font size.

Help me with all possible alternatives to adjust the size of this emoji(unicode) specifically.

Any useful resource link will also work. :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The size of the emoji is determined by the font size.

They all have the same unicode string, just at diffrent sizes

To change the size of anything in the console, you need to change the font-size of the terminal you are using. Note, that this will scale everything

Comment: Thanks :) I got your point. But what if I just want to change the size of emoji(unicode) instead of changing the size of the terminal. Is there any mechanism ?

Comment: I dont think that's possible, just as changing the size of single letters isn't possible in the terminal